# Alter the value retrieved by filter_input in tests

Tags: php

I used to modify superglobals in tests to test behavior of classes handling HTTP request input, like this:

```
$_COOKIE = ['foo'=>'bar'];
$request = Request::create()
Assert::same('bar', $request->getCookie('foo'));
```

This works fine until I read the `$_COOKIE` array inside `Request::create`.

But when I read the input using `filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'bar')`, I get `NULL` in the test - obviously modifying `$_COOKIE` does not modify return value of `filter_input`.

My question is how to write a test specifying a cookie value for a class/method that is using `filter_input`?

Thanks.

Comment: What kinds of tests are we talking about here? Because I'm wondering why are you testing a framework (or a delivery mechanism) instead of your business logic.

Comment: Simple answer - I write a low-level framework utility that I want to test :)